# Unity3D bird flying back and forth

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a bird moving across screen along x axis.

```
bird.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (pos1, pos2, (Mathf.Abs(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
```

Using this in Update() the bird flies only once. I want that after it flies to the right, it should wait 2-3 seconds and then fly back with a different sprite.
transform.translate doesn't work like this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to put in another LERP for going the other direction and have a variable for which way the bird is flying so roughly:

```
bool goleft;

if(goleft)
{
     if(transform.position != pos2)
     {
          transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (pos1, pos2, (Mathf.Abs(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
     }
     else
     {
           goleft = false;
           //change the direction the bird is facing here
     }
}
else
{
     if(transform.position != pos1)
     {
          transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (pos2, pos1, (Mathf.Abs(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
     }
     else
     {
           goleft = true;
           //change the direction the bird is facing here
     }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You could use the WaitForSeconds() function in the else statements to make the bird wait. Sorry, not sure about changing the sprite!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it shows the bird only once going from left to right. It doesn't come from right again. And I tried WaitForSeconds(), but I'm sure I didn't use it right, hence no result. I tried Invocation too.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but i would start here:

```
Vector3[] posts;
int current = 0;
float speed = 5.0f;
float threshold = Single.Epsilon;
float delay = 2.0f;

public void Update() {
    if(!waiting && posts.Length > 0)
    {
        if(!Mathf.Approximately((posts[current].position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude, threshold)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posts[current].position, step);
        }
        else StartCoroutine("Next");
    }
}

IEnumerator Next() {
    waiting = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    current = (current + 1) % posts.Length;
    waiting = false;
}
```

This will also allow you to have as many posts as you want to have, and all your movement dynamics can be handled in `Next()`, whereas, if you want him to go from post `0`...`1`...`2`...`3`...`0`...`1`.. or `0`...`1`...`2`...`3`...`2`...`1`...

If you want the latter you just change `current = (current + 1) % posts.Length;` to `Mathf.PingPong(current + 1, posts.Length);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go a bit like this:

```
float flipCooldown
float defaultFlipCooldown = 2.0f;
bool isGoingRight;
Vector2 pos1;
Vector2 pos2;

void Start() {
    flipCooldown = defaultFlipCooldown;
    isGoingRight = true;
    pos1 = new Vector2(0, 0);
    pos2 = new Vector2(5, 0); // whatever floats your boat
}

void Update()
{
    Vector2 initialPosition = null;
    Vector2 finalPosition = null;

    if (flipCooldown <= 0) {
        isGoingRight = !isGoingRight
        flipCooldown = defaultFlipCooldown;
        ChangeSprite();
    }

    if (isGoingRight) {
        initialPos = pos1;
        finalPos = pos2;
    } else {
        initialPos = pos2;
        finalPos = pos1;
    }

    bird.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (initialPos, finalPos, (Mathf.Abs(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);

    flipCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

What you want to get is that the `Time.deltaTime` is decreasing the cooldown for the bird to turn. You can easily change the cooldown in the `defaultFlipCooldown` variable. When it's done going one way, it'll just flip the position and the `Lerp` function will do the rest of the work. The `ChangeSprite` function will be just a `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite` change.

If you don't want fix positions, you can calculate how much it'll fly, define the final position and just change the `pos1` and `pos2`.

It's also important to note that `WaitForSeconds` will just work with **Coroutines** that is a concept for working with threads, never in a method like `Update`. You can learn more about Coroutines in Unity's manual: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html